# How can I solve Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

the exception is:

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NullPointerException    
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source),

at PlayGame.setCards(PlayGame.java:42)

at PlayGame.startGame(PlayGame.java:190)

at forms.PlayGame.<init>(PlayGame.java:36)
```

this is my code

```
public class PlayGame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private LogicGame logic = new LogicGame();
    private ImageIcon img1;
    private ImageIcon img2;

     // Creates new form PlayGame
    public PlayGame() {
        initComponents();
        startGame();
    }

    private void setCards() {
        int[] numbers = logica.getCardNumbers();

        Carta1.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[0] + ".png")));
        Carta2.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[1] + ".png")));
        Carta3.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[2] + ".png")));
        Carta4.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[3] + ".png")));
        Carta5.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[4] + ".png")));
        Carta6.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[5] + ".png")));
        Carta7.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[6] + ".png")));
        Carta8.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[7] + ".png")));
        Carta9.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[8] + ".png")));
        Carta10.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[9] + ".png")));
        Carta11.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[10] + ".png")));
        Carta12.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[11] + ".png")));
        Carta13.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[12] + ".png")));
        Carta14.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[13] + ".png")));
        Carta15.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[14] + ".png")));
        Carta16.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/c" + numbers[15] + ".png")));
    }

    public void startGame() {
        if (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Pulse si, para jugar!. ", "Empezar Juego", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)) {
            setCards();
            hour.setVisible(false);
            iniciarTiempo();
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the javadoc of `Class#getResource(..)`.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to read

Comment: Put `img` dir in the src and get rid of all the `..`s in the paths

Comment: img is a package, there I have only pictures.

Comment: So then get rid of all the `..`s

Comment: like this:  "src/img/c"

Comment: No, just like you have it currently, but get rid of the dots

Comment: hmmmm like this "/img/c" + numbers[0] + ".png"

Comment: Yes, I tried and solved the Exception.  Thank you for help me

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't see any variable with the name "logica", 2) but the problems is in ure array numbers[], the exception is telling u that ur are calling index doesnt exist in your array

Comment: Yeah, there is logic, not logica  and logic is the object of one class "LogicGame "